# How to run script in pnpm workspace that doesn't exist in other workspaces

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm, turborepo

I'm trying to run pnpm script from the root of the monorepo, I am able to run perfectly common scripts like "dev", "build" etc. However my workspaces have unique scripts let's say **mobile** workspace has ***dev:ios*** which other workspaces do not have it in their scripts. I'm not sure how to run this from the root of the monorepo.

These are commands I tried which gave an error:

```bash
turbo run dev:ios
turbo run dev:ios -r
turbo run dev:ios --filter mobile
```

```bash
pnpm run dev:ios
pnpm run dev:ios -r
pnpm run dev:ios --filter mobile
```

Answer (score 3):

Flags that are passed to the run command should be placed before the script name. So, these are the correct commands:

```bash
pnpm run -r dev:ios
pnpm run --filter=mobile dev:ios
```

Any flags that are placed after the script name are appended to the executed command from the script.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Rather than:

```
pnpm run dev:ios -r
```

It should be:

```
pnpm run -r dev:ios
```

turbo doesn't have -r/--recursive